# Consuming SOAP web service for a cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, soap

I am trying to consume a SOAP web service into a cocoa application. The return value which is printing in the log is an HTML error page.

My Main objective is to pass two parameters to the web service and get a value in response. Can anyone please suggest correct way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

It could be any number of things. For startes: you may be hitting the wrong URL, you may be sending invalid data and the server is not returning a valid error. The best thing to do is check what you are doing against any docs you may have, then contact the person working on the server side of the project for help debugging.

I know that is not a very specific answer, but I don't have a lot to go on. Hope it helps.